# How to change the scrolling text in CSS or JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I made a scrolling text in `<div>`. It takes 15s for one time scrolling. I like to change texts in scrolling one after another. How could be done?
My CSS is

```
/*Text scrolling*/
.scroll-right {
 height: 50px;
 font-size: 20px;
 background: #D00000;   
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 color: white;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-family: Sans-serif;
}
.scroll-right p {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 line-height: 50px;
 text-align: center;
 /* Starting position */
 -moz-transform:translateX(-100%);
 -webkit-transform:translateX(-100%);   
 transform:translateX(-100%);
 /* Apply animation to this element */  
 -moz-animation: scroll-right 15s linear infinite;
 -webkit-animation: scroll-right 15s linear infinite;
 animation: scroll-right 15s linear infinite;
}
/* Move it (define the animation) */
@-moz-keyframes scroll-right {
 0%   { -moz-transform: translateX(-100%); }
 100% { -moz-transform: translateX(100%); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes scroll-right {
 0%   { -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); }
 100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); }
}
@keyframes scroll-right {
 0%   { 
 -moz-transform: translateX(-100%); /* Browser bug fix */
 -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); /* Browser bug fix */
 transform: translateX(-100%);      
 }
 100% { 
 -moz-transform: translateX(100%); /* Browser bug fix */
 -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); /* Browser bug fix */
 transform: translateX(100%); 
 }
}
```

HTML is

```
<div class="scroll-right">
<p>...To rent...</p>
</div>
```

First time scrolling is "...To rent...", then disappear and next time appear again, it should appear with "..For the last three months...". How can I do that?
The code is shown in [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Thomas_nyan/5bcttpe9/7/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would include both texts you want as children in the HTML.

```
<div class="scroll-right">
<p>...To rent...</p>
<p>...For the last three months...</p>
</div>
```

Then make the animation 30 seconds, but complete at 50% in your keyframes, so that you have a 15 second animation repeating with a 15 second delay. Put a 15 second delay on the second child so that they alternate.

Here's the CSS without the prefixes so you get the idea.

```
@keyframes scroll-right {
   0%   { 
   transform: translateX(-100%);      
 }
   50% { 
   transform: translateX(100%); 
 }
   100% { 
   transform: translateX(100%); 
 }


.scroll-right p:nth-child(1) {
   animation: scroll-right 30s linear infinite;
}
.scroll-right p:nth-child(2) {
   animation: scroll-right 30s linear 15s infinite;
}
```

**EDIT** Here is a complete working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5bcttpe9/17/

Comment: Yes it does. Thank you.